Is it possible to log multiple states of the same object using SQLAlchemy?
I am trying to use SQLAlchemy to repeatedly log what is happening to one object. Some example code is below, which demonstrates my aim.
from sqlalchemy.orm import session maker, declarative_base, Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, String, Integer
from random import randint
Base = declaritive_base()
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, auto increment=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    age: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer)
    favorite_color: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    
    def __init__(self, name, favorite_color):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 0
        self.favorite_color = favorite_color

    def change_favorite_color(self):
        colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
        self.favorite_color = colors[randint(0, 2)]

    def increase_age(self):
        self.age += 1


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mydb.db', echo=False)
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

Session = session maker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

susan = Person('Susan', 'pink')
for i in range(50):
    session.add(susan)
    session.commit()
    susan.increase_age()
    if susan.age % 5 == 0:
        susan.change_favorite_color()


After it is finished, I would like to have a log of what Susan's favourite colour was at every age. Presently, I end up with only what her final favourite colour is when she reaches 49.
I have found a couple of solutions. For example, at every age, generate a new person object to represent Susan specifically at that age, add that to the session, then disregard it and generate a new object for the next year. Also solutions involving a class to store only the recorded data, and it is one of these that is created every time step is committed.
Both of these seem unnecessarily inelegant; I want to simply alter the attributes of the Susan object, log the current state, and then continue modifying until I want to log again and so on. I do not have an excellent understanding of SQLAlchemy, and from the difficulty I have had with this, it occurs to me that it may be fundamentally against how SQLAlchemy is designed, and if so, why? This seems like a fairly natural thing you might want to do, and is it still possible, or are there any other libraries that cater to this better?

Are you familiar with the term "temporal table"?

Also, this: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/examples.html#versioning-objects

You can do this with sqlalchemy ORM events after_insert and after_update. Also see listen().
I modified your example a bit to show this. The mappings are gone because I have sqlalchemy 1.4, not 2.0, but this is just to show how the events work.
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer, event
from random import randint
Base = declarative_base()
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    pid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
    favorite_color = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name, favorite_color):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 0
        self.favorite_color = favorite_color

    def change_favorite_color(self):
        colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
        self.favorite_color = colors[randint(0, 2)]

    def increase_age(self):
        self.age += 1

def log_age_color(mapper, connection, target):
    print(f"{target.name}, {target.age}, {target.favorite_color}")

event.listen(Person, 'after_insert', log_age_color)
event.listen(Person, 'after_update', log_age_color)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mydb.db', echo=False)
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

susan = Person('Susan', 'pink')
for i in range(10):
    session.add(susan)
    session.commit()
    susan.increase_age()
    if susan.age % 5 == 0:
        susan.change_favorite_color()

Output:
Susan, 0, pink
Susan, 1, pink
Susan, 2, pink
Susan, 3, pink
Susan, 4, pink
Susan, 5, blue
Susan, 6, blue
Susan, 7, blue
Susan, 8, blue
Susan, 9, blue

